# Using "not" Jquery selector does not deselect

Tags: jquery

I have several `div`s  with the same classes that need to be hidden after certain interval, except one. I identified the one with an `id` attribute:

```
  <div id="reload-server-status-message" class="alert alert-warning" style="display: none">
    <strong>Please wait! It may take up to 2 minutes!</strong>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning" style="display: none">
    <strong>I am dif 2. there are yet three more divs, but I am not gonna show them</strong>
  </div>
```

The script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setTimeout(function(){
    $(".alert:not(#reload-server-status)").remove();
  }, 5000);

  $('#reload-server-status').bind('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#reload-server-status-message").show();
      document.location.href="<%= admin_server_managements_obtain_statuses_path %>";     
  });
 })
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w5xqoahy/ not selector works with id

Comment: @BrettGregson
It works! But why not working with the .remove() ?

Comment: @Hairi it does work with remove. Just replace .fadeOut with .remove and you'll see that all tests disappear except #not-me in the fiddle provided by BrettGregson

Comment: You have the id wrong. The id in your not selector is `#reload-server-status` while the element has `#reload-server-status-message`. Voting to close because of small typographical error.